# What's the best way to handle touches with multiple subviews and viewcontrollers in a window

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a somewhat specific scenario and I am unsure of the best way to deal with it.

I will note that both ways I have tried works but I am looking for maybe the optimal or proper way.

**Scenario**

I am building a UIWindow that will be presented above an application. The UIWindow will contain multiple layers of views, each layer could contain floating subviews that are able to be dragged by the user and each layer is controlled by it's own View controller as well. If the user does not touch any of the subviews, it will pass the touches through the views and the UIWindow down to the application to handle it like normal.

**Option 1** - Letting each UIView/Subview handle the hit-test. Basically the views themselves are the ones that implement `pointInside` and `hitTest` which makes me believe that the views themselves are supposed to do this check. In the UIWindow, I will then have to loop through each subview, and their subviews to find the hit one. I can also do just plainly `hitTest` but I have to then explicitly check that my sub viewcontrollers "main" views (self.view) were not the ones that should be dragged.

**Option 2** - Letting each UIViewController handle the `pointInside` thing, a custom method that is. Basically this would make me have to implement a custom method in each UIViewController that loops through it's views subviews to then return a BOOL weather or not it was hit. I would have to manually call this method from the UIWindow > VC-main.sub-2.check() + VC-main.sub-1.check()

**Option 3** - ????

As I said, I've got both of these methods to work, but none of them feel very very elegant so I am wondering if anyone has some good idea.

Here is an image of the general layout.

[image]

Comment: You may find this useful http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: @teamnorge I've had a read, and it doesn't touch on UIViewControllers at all, it is more explaining how the hitTest works - which I kind of already knew. However, it does give me some idea (that I've actually touched upon before) in which I would have to create custom placeholder views in each UIViewController-sub-1/2 that sole purpose was to ignore touches to not have to deal with this in the UIWindow itself. I guess I will explore that further.